# Calling a textview from a textview array results null

Tags: android, arrays, nullpointerexception, textview

I had made 5 textviews, textview1 to textview5.
Then I created a textview array like this:-

```
TextView tvArr[] = new TextView[] { textview1, textview2, textview3, textview4, textview5 };
```

When I am using the setText method, it is throwing NullPointerException -

```
tvArr[3].setText("Done");
```

Please help me find out what I've missed out, and thanks in advance...

Edit: I want to find out how the set text method is throwing NullPointerException, I am not asking to troubleshoot my code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I am not understanding what here is throwing NullPointerException ?

Comment: what is null point error ? @PdUnique

Comment: You have to put a object in the array slots. You are trying to set something that does not exist.

Comment: Are you initialising all the textview before adding them to the array?

Comment: _"I had made 5 textviews, textview1 to textview5."_ How exactly? You could edit the question and add your code. Just typing `TextView textview1;` won't be enough. The object will be `null`. You probably want to use `findViewById()` to find the TextViews if you defined them in the layout XML file. And `findViewById()` may return `null` if you made a mistake somewhere, like calling it with the wrong id or calling it in a wrong place like before `setContentView()` for example.

Comment: post your entire code, this will help us to help you?

Comment: Check this out too first [Java tutorial by Oracle -Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: I have initialised the TextViews

Comment: _"I have initialised the TextViews"_ How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After declaring the text views array, you have to initialize the items in it. Use either

```
tvArr[3] = new TextView(this);
tvArr[3].setText("Done");
parentLayout.addView(tvArr[3]);
```

or

```
tvArr[3] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_view);
tvArr[3].setText("Done");
```

Comment: Adding objects to an array should be like
TextView[] tvArr = new TextView[5]; 
 tvArr[0] = textView1; tvArr[1] = textView2; etc. Then you can use it as tvArr[0].setText("Done");

Comment: Those are not the only possible ways. For example the Oracle Java documentation page linked in the question comments gives an example of a similar way (albeit with primitives) as the OP used: `int[] anArray = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000};`. It should be perfectly valid. Of course assuming that the objects added to the array are non-null.